# How to share a folder on Windows 7

Tags: c#, networking, directory

I am using C# to create a folder and share it on the network:

```
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(FolderPath))
{
      System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderPath);
      // Calling Win32_Share class to create a shared folder
      ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Share");
      // Get the parameter for the Create Method for the folder
      ManagementBaseObject inParams = managementClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
      ManagementBaseObject outParams;
      // Assigning the values to the parameters
      inParams["Description"] = Description;
      inParams["Name"] = ShareName;
      inParams["Path"] = FolderPath;
      inParams["Type"] = 0x0;
      // Finally Invoke the Create Method to do the process
      outParams = managementClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
      // Validation done here to check sharing is done or not
      if ((uint)(outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value) != 0)
      {
           //MessageBox.Show("Folder might be already in share or unable to share the directory");
      }
}
```

It works on XP, but I am not able to share a folder from this code on Windows 7.

Can anyone tell me how I can share a folder in Windows 7 using C#?

Comment: What error/exception do you get? Have you tried running your code as Administrator, in case UAC is an issue?

Comment: There is no error in this code.I got 
outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value = 2
And after that i checked the folder and i found no sharing on that folder.

Comment: try to run your application as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Your application will need to be running with Administrative access in order to share a folder.

If you have a look at the following link, it talks about what appears to be the same situation  as what you are dealing with. About half way down there is an accepted answer which walks through the additional actions required for it to work on a Windows 7 machine.

Link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/de213b61-dc7e-4f33-acdb-893aa96837fa

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Replace the

```
\
```

in your path with

```
/
```